# Margins on composite Chart

Tags: dc.js

I've recently tried to add margins to composite charts and the charts are plotting to the left of the Y axis.

[image: Results]

The charts are built dynamically. I tried more combinations of values for margins, but it didn't work. I want to add margin-left because some charts have big values on y axis.

Here is the esential code:

```
hist_margins = {top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 40}
charts[i]
        .compose([
            dc.barChart(charts[i])
                .dimension(dim)
                .group(static_group)
                .colors('#ccc')
                .barPadding(0.1)
                .controlsUseVisibility(true),
            dc.barChart(charts[i])
                .dimension(dim)
                .colors('rgb(85, 160, 185)')
                .group(group)
                .barPadding(0.1)
                .controlsUseVisibility(true)
                .brushOn(false),
        ])

      var min = dim.bottom(1)[0][it.variable],
          max = dim.top(1)[0][it.variable];
      charts[i]
          .width(w_hist)
          .height(h_hist) 
          .margins(hist_margins)
          .dimension(dim)
          .group(group)
          .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([min, max])) 
          .xAxisLabel(it.variable, 20)
          .xUnits(dc.units.fp.precision(it.precision*1.5))
          .brushOn(true)
          .transitionDuration(0) 
          .renderTitle(true)
          .title(function (d) {
            return it.variable + ': ' + d.value
          })
          .controlsUseVisibility(true);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for restoring the screenshots!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of dc.js 3.1.4, you would have to call `.margins()` before calling `.compose()` in order for the values to be reflected in the child charts.

However, thanks to [a PR by Keith Dahlby](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/1365), this limitation has been eliminated.

So, you can either upgrade to dc.js 3.1.5 (just released), or you can call `.margins()` first.